# Buttons from cloned section not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery scripts. I managed to clone one section of the form dynamically but my button to display the ckeditor's div in the cloned section is not working. It still listening to the button from the original section and will only show the ckeditor's div(but unable to edit all of them except the original) when the original button was clicked. Here is my code:-

```
for(i=num; i<value; i++){
    var newSlot = $('#slot' + i).clone().attr('id','slot' + (i+1));

    newSlot.find('.heading-slot').attr('id', 'ID' + (i+1) + '_slot').html('Slot ' + (i+1)); //add new slot name

    newSlot.find('.other_message').hide();
    newSlot.find('.select_instruction').on('change', function () {  
        $(this).next('.other_message').toggle((this.value) == "Other")
    });


    newSlot.find('.extra_instruction').hide();
    //the button here is not working as I wanted
    newSlot.find('.btnAdditional').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('.extra_instruction').show();
    });

    $('#slot' + i).after(newSlot);
}
```

html code

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="button" id="btn_Additional" name="btn_Additional" class="btnAdditional btn btn-info">Additional Instruction</button>
            <div class="extra_instruction">
                <textarea id="input_add_instruction" name="add_instruction[]" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'input_add_instruction' );</script>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone guide me on this?? Please I'm very new to this. Thanks in advances..

Answer (score 0):

The clone function not only clones the html but also the event listeners, instead of cloning try creating your element and adding the event listeners properly.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how it should be done?

Comment: Not really, since you example is not complete, I don't have the content of the #slot element. Since you work with CKEditor, why not make a plugin with your functionality. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample